# John's is a world of misery

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it acceptable to say "John's is a world of misery" instead of for example, "John's world is one of misery", or "John's world is miserable?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly correct. It has a literary sound -- you would be unlikely to hear it in ordinary conversation.

Comment: Really? I had not noticed that.

Comment: @WS2 - I'd be interested to hear a more everyday version. Even talking about a world of misery is not exactly common in my experience.

Comment: Yeah, I would find it unusual in ordinary conversation, but have known people who might use the idiom.

Comment: John's world of misery was made up by me solely for this question. I originally read this type of phrase in a review of British circuit comedian Jethro's 'Beast of Bodmin Moor' video. The review said, "Jethro's is a world of slappers and travelling door-to-door salesmen."

Comment: @chaslyfromUK How about *Jane's is bound to be a more practical idea than Susie's*.